# how to add data to my firebase upon email and password registration using angularfire2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

So after creating a user in my firebase with the (createUser) firebase method.
How do i then immediately add data into my firebase database. Here is a code below.

```
    createUser(email: string, password: string, username:string) {
        this.af.auth.createUser({ email, password })
    **so instead of the console log below**
     .then((user) => console.log(`Create User Success:`, user))
** i will rather add the username string into my firebase like this**
   const adddatatobase = this.af.database().ref('usernamestore').push({
userdetails:username
});
          .catch(e => console.error(`Create User Failure:`, e));
      }
```

I have tried the code above and i have not been very successful. Any help at all with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the script you want to execute inside your response:

```
createUser(email: string, password: string, username:string) {
  this.af.auth.createUser({ email, password })
    .then(user => {
      const users = this.af.database.object('/profile');
      users.update({
        user.uid: { username: username }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(`Create User Failure: ${err}`));
}
```

Comment: just tried your answer but it did not work... i keep getting this error (Cannot read property 'af' of null)

Comment: Did you call `AngularFire` in your constructor? `constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}`. Can you post a Plunker? It's easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help...i have added the constructor and am getting a compilation error saying {Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature} the error is base on this line; `const adddatatobase = this.af.database().ref('usernamestore');`

Comment: I'm not sure where you're trying to push that information. Personally, I'd create a new `profile` item in my database to save all users' information and set the username there. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer it worked.. what if i want to save user all user information and not just keep updating a firebase path. At the moment i can only update the database and not store... any help with that. thanks

Comment: but you're saving the information, just in a different path. when you call the update, it will look if there's an existing `key`, if there isn't, it will create one. that way, if you store user information in `profile`, for example, when you call `update` it will create a unique key using that user's `uid` and store the information there.

Comment: thanks @drbishop but  `user.uid: { username: username }` throwsback error saying  'Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.' what could i have done wrong?